# Moving static IP address to a different VM on Azure

Tags: azure

I have to VM's (VM1 and VM2) in the same resource group and I want to move public IP address of VM1 to VM2. Is it possible? IP address assigned to VM1 is static.

I can see the dissociate option but I am not sure if dissociating will release the current public IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassociating will give you the warning that it might release it, but in my experience I've been able to re-attach and keep the same IP.

If this is in production then I would do it at a time where you have time to update everything if it is released.

That being said, I do believe if you unintentionally release the IP and it hasn't already been re-allocated then you could get support to give you it back. That's a lot of 'if's though.